# error -->The pipe 'filter' could not be found while using angular4

Tags: angular

I am doing unit-testing in angular4 -node.js deployed project.And while testing i found this error -

```
Template parse errors:
The pipe 'filter' could not be found ("
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let[ERROR ->] dat of result | filter:filterdata| 
paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p };let i = index ">
```

so i added these two modules to my module.ts and spec.ts files -->

```
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
 imports: [PipesModule
 ],
```

And for this particular module import -->

```
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';
```

Error -->Cannot find module '../../pipes/pipes.module'.

Please help resolve the issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must include FilterPipe in the declarations and exports of your PipesModule.

Comment: can you please elaborate it

Comment: Also do not forget to import the filter in the module where you want to use it

Answer (score 5):

**Angular 7/8 - nested routes**

If you're using some **nested routes** and you're using the filter in child components, remove the filter from app.modules.ts and :

**For custom filter**

Import the filter in the declaration section of your child childmodule.module.ts

**For ng2-search-filter**

Import Ng2SearchPipeModule in the import section of your child childmodule.module.ts

Answer (score 2):

Hello Here is the sample example you can check it.

> App.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, Component, Injectable  } from '@angular/core';
import { LimitToPipe } from './pipes/limit-to.pipe'; // your pipe path 

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   LimitToPipe
 ]
});
```

> Create limit-to.pipe.ts

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'limitTo'
    })
    export class LimitToPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: string, args: string): string {
        const limit = args ? parseInt(args, 10) : 10;
        const trail = '...';
        return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
      }
    }
```

> import in your component

```
 import { LimitToPipe } from '../pipes/limit-to.pipe';
```

> in your html

```
{{ name | limitTo :60 : 0 }}
```

> Unit Test (limit-to.pipe.spec.ts)

```
    import { LimitToPipe } from './limit-to.pipe'; // your custom pipe path

    describe('Pipe: LimitTo', () => {
      let pipe: LimitToPipe;

      beforeEach(() => {
        pipe = new LimitToPipe();
      });

      it('show 3 dot when string length is grater ther 15 chartacter', () => {
        expect(pipe.transform('my name is vikram sharma', '15')).toBe('my name is vikr...');
      });

      it('show full string when string length is less then 15 character', () => {
        expect(pipe.transform('my name is vikram sharma', '200')).toBe('my name is vikram sharma');
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you ma'am for accept my answer, please also upvote my answer.

Comment: Hi vikram, i have created looking as above but error still persists . please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076413/after-creating-custom-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-i-am-still-get

Comment: ok ma'amm but i have tested in my system with unit test and it is working

Comment: this is the stackbiz url and it is working properly
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-fileter

Comment: I am noob, and want to know where exactly (in html) I need to change and add the code. Do I need to add changes in my search input.

Answer (score 0):

### **You can install the Search Filter Plugin**.

Install the third-party search filter package with npm command:

`npm install ng2-search-filter`

Then import it in the app.module.ts,

`import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';`

and add it into the imports array,

`imports:[Ng2SearchPipeModule]`

https://www.remotestack.io/angular-search-filter-pipe-with-ng2-search-filter-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

add to imports Ng2SearchPipeModule, example:

import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';

...

```
  imports:[Ng2SearchPipeModule],
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Answer (score 0):

You must include Pipe in the declarations and provider of your module where you are consuming

Answer (score -1):

In Angular a good technique for sharing common directives, components, pipes, etc. is to use a so called shared module.

Those modules declare and export common parts, to make them usable for any of your other modules.

```
// other imports
import { filterPipe} from './{your-path}';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // dep modules
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    filterPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    filterPipe
  ]
})
export class PipesModule {}
```

and then,

mport the created ApplicationPipesModule module into the modules where your pipe is going to be used, by adding it to the imports array

```
// other imports
import { PipesModule } from './{your-path}';   

    @NgModule({
     imports: [
       // other dep modules
       PipesModule 
     ],
     declarations: [],
     exports: []
    })
    export class MyModule1 {}
```

Comment: when i put this -->import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';  in module.ts file, it says ...cannot find module  './filter.pipe'

Comment: this is just a sample and you have to provide absolute path of your pipe module

Comment: hi sajeetharan.. i have created a custom pipe module.. but the error persists... please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076413/after-creating-custom-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-i-am-still-get

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava after explaining in detail and you dont get answer. i have explained what phil has suggested in detail