# After creating custom Search Pipe to Dynamically Filter results , i am still getting Failed: parse errors: The pipe 'filter' could not be found

Tags: javascript, angular

I am deploying a project in angular4 and node.js. I created a custom pipe filter file named  filter.pipe.js. And all the related code. Still i am getting the error -->

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'filter' could not be found ("
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let[ERROR ->] dat of result | filter:filterdata| 
 paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p };let i = index ">
  "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/TransactionComponent.html@220:23
```

**CODE**

***filter.pipe.ts***

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


 @Pipe({
   name: 'filter'
  })

 export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(items: any[], filterdata: string): any[] {
 if(!items) return [];
 if(!filterdata) return items;
  filterdata = filterdata.toLowerCase();
  return items.filter( it => {
  return it.toLowerCase().includes(filterdata);
   });
   }
  }
```

***app.module.ts***

```
 import { FilterPipe} from './transaction/filter.pipe';
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


 @NgModule({
 imports: [ ..],

   declarations: [ FilterPipe,..]
  )}
```

***app.component.ts***

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
 import { FilterPipe} from '../transaction/filter.pipe';
```

***app.component.html***

```
   <td style="width:50%">
              <input class="form-control" id="input1-group1 " 
  style="margin-top:20px" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter 
  Search Text"
  [(ngModel)]="filterdata">

 </td>

  <tr *ngFor="let dat of result | filter:filterdata| paginate: { 
    itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p };let i = index ">

 //some more html
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The "tags" you attach to your question ( and often selected just as you type your question ) are meant to categorize the topics that your question is about. As noted, these do populate automatically as you type certain "terms" but this won't always be completely accurate of what your question is about. Please pay attention to these as you add new questions. Then make sure that the only selected "tags" are those which relate "directly" to the question you are actually asking. Other components of you "stack" which are not part of the question code should be removed.

Comment: ma'am can you show result reponse

Comment: the result comes on console. But it is not displaying as it says. 
 ERROR TypeError: it.toLowerCase is not a function
    at eval (filter.pipe.ts:25)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at FilterPipe.transform (filter.pipe.ts:24)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TransactionComponent.html:221)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13058)

Comment: And after removing .to.toLowerCase i get error -->ERROR TypeError: it.includes is not a function
    at eval (filter.pipe.ts:25)

Comment: "it" is object not string, first you check what value comes in "it"

Comment: ma'am also can you show the json response of result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58909274/9565877

Answer (score 0):

here is my sample app you can test it on stackblitz
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-fileter)

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { FilterPipe} from './filter.pipe';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, FilterPipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> app.component.ts

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
        import { FilterPipe} from './filter.pipe';
        @Component({
         selector: 'my-app',
         templateUrl: './app.component.html',
         styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
        })
        export class AppComponent  {
         name = 'Angular 5';
         public filterdata = null;

         public result = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Vikram'},
            { id: 2, name: 'Vivek'},
            { id: 3, name: 'Vijay'}
         ]
        }
```

> filter.pipe.ts

```
        import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


        @Pipe({
         name: 'filter'
        })

        export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
         transform(items: any[], filterdata: string): any[] {
         if(!items) return [];
         if(!filterdata) return items;
          console.log(filterdata);
          filterdata = filterdata.toString().toLowerCase();
          return items.filter( it => {
            console.log(it);
            return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterdata);
           });
         }
        }
```

> app.component.html

```
    <input class="form-control" id="input1-group1 " 
    style="margin-top:20px" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter 
    Search Text"
    [(ngModel)]="filterdata">

    <table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th> <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of result | filter:filterdata ">
    <td>{{data.id}}</td> <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    </tr>  
    </tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: here vikram i have a question. In this piece of code -->  return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterdata); ..it is specifically for name...i want the option for all the columns. ..and the error lies in there ..ERROR TypeError: it.toLowerCase is not a function  And after removing .toLowerCase() ...it gives the error ERROR TypeError: it.includes is not a function at eval (filter.pipe.ts:25)

Comment: ok ma'am please can you provide your column name with values. it will easy for me for making

Comment: you can use this if you using angular material.io
https://stackblitz.com/angular/klbqqvjjgjv

Comment: thanks vikram... but there are more than 15 columns. i may not be able to add them. thanks so far. but y do you need column names... will you include individual column names in --> return items.filter( it => {
            console.log(it);
            return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterdata);

Comment: hi vikram, can you please help here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50095904/how-to-display-the-datetime-popup-in-the-table-row

Comment: check this one  ..this one is correct...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097450/to-make-two-ng2-datetimepickers-and-obtain-its-value

Comment: datepicker is not opening in your case and proper alignment of datepicker, is it correct ?

Comment: no the datepicker is not opening ...is done... please check the other link ... improper alignment and use two date time pickers

Comment: are you using bootstrap css

Comment: if you are using bootstrap 3 and you need to use form-inline class
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/

Comment: yes i am using and i have mentioned it entirely . Link --> .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097450/to-make-two-ng2-datetimepickers-and-obtain-its-value

Comment: yes i have included the links of bootstrap3 and bootstrap 4 in my index.html file