# How to display the datetime popup in the table row

Tags: html, css, angular2-forms, datetimepicker

I am using ng2 date-timepicker and i want the popup of the datetime to be displayed completely so that i can select the date and time. I am displaying the input box in the table for its proper alignment with other input boxes and validations to be displayed below it.

How it appears right now is-

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH2BZ.png)

**component.html**

```
  <div style="padding-left: 0; padding-bottom:10px">
  <div class="row form-inline">
  <div class="col-lg-12 ">

  <form [formGroup]="dateTransactionForm">
    <div class=" form-inline">
      <table id="searchTableStyle">
        <tr>
          <td >
            <div class="form-group">
                <angular2-date-picker class="form-control" 
   [formControl]="dateTransactionForm.controls['fromDateTransaction']" 
                [(ngModel)]="date"  [settings]="settings"></angular2- 
   date-picker>
   </div>
  </td>
:
:
://other html code

</div>
```

**component.css**

```
#searchTableStyle{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:transparent;
    height : 150px;
 }
```

And rest all the other data from the of ts from :

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datetimepicker
```

Comment: Can you share the html and css code of the entire page. Maybe the transaction table is on the top. Need to debug.

Comment: Better if you can create a plunker/stackblitz

Comment: thank you arvind. i found the solution. i need to make --> overflow:visible

Comment: Cool. Great Sucheta!

Comment: can you please help in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097450/to-make-two-ng2-datetimepickers-and-obtain-its-value