# Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'filter' could not be found in angular

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-filters, angular-template

imported this filter

```
// search module
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
```

HTML code for it

```
//search

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search">

//Assigned filter to table

 <tr *ngFor="let bookName of NameOfBookList | filter:searchText">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did your declare it in your module `declarations[]`?

Comment: Is 'NameOfBookList' a string array?

Comment: Unable to [reproduce](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrdwke-angular-search-pipe-uubbrk)! Can you provide Stackblitz? and Provide sample data of `NameOfBookList `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `Ng2SearchPipeModule` ONLY to the imports worked for me. When adding to the declarations I got an error in my browser tools stating that there was an unexpected delcaration for `Ng2SearchPipeModule`.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Then in my markup:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="term">
...
<tbody *ngFor="let d of myList |filter:term">
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: Module-imports *never* go anywhere but inside the `imports`-array, as `declarations` is for components/pipes/directives only.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. please add import Ng2SearchPipeModule in the import section of your child childmodule.module.ts.

working solution -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075567/error-the-pipe-filter-could-not-be-found-while-using-angular4