# filter pipe not working in angular 10 with ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, search, filter, pipe

After npm i ng2-search-filter and importing to app.module.ts, filter pipe not working. 'the pipe 'filter' could not be found.

```
//app.module.ts
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
//at NgModule
imports: [Ng2SearchPipeModule],


//search.html
<ion-searchbar class="p-0" [(ngModel)]="term"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="p-0"*ngFor="let remittance of filterData | filter:term">
     </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

/// got an error in '| filter:term' - The pipe 'filter' could not be found
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error? Also, please check whether you have imported Ng2SearchPipeModule in app.module.ts

Comment: Like Dashti said, make sure you're imports are ok - you can refer [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56268383/error-template-parse-errors-the-pipe-filter-could-not-be-found-in-angular)

Comment: have you added pipe modules in .module.ts file

Comment: I have imported the Ng2SearchPipeMododule in app.module.ts

Comment: everything works fine until I put the filter pipe in the *ngFor. It shows "The pipe 'filter' could not be found"

Comment: Have you followed the basic example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter)

Comment: That might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)